# Microsoft Graph API with Azure User Provisioning

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-management-api

What I want to do is quite simple: provision Office 365 and Azure Account from my Web App. And I want it to be available not only for me but for all the IT Departments (from other organizations too) that logs in my App.

From my understanding the steps I have to take are:

- Register App on `apps.dev.microsoft.com` and get ID And Secret.
- Enable the Scopes I'm interested in (in my case `Directory.ReadWrite.All` and `User.ReadWrite.All`) -- Enabled from both Delegated Permissions and Application Permissions
- Gone through the LOGIN PROCESS

  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=[My Client]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[My Account]/Account/Office&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20User.Read%20offline_access%20Directory.ReadWrite.All
- Confirm the code I receive back on my Return URL

`POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token?...secret and so on...`

Now what I get is an object with Access Token, Renew Token and so on and so forth.

If I use it to get users, it's all working:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`

But when I try to perform other operations the token seems invalid.

For instance:

- Get Azure subscriptions (the account is admin of several subscription):

`https://management.core.windows.net/subscriptions`  ==> UNAUTHORIZED

What I'm doing wrong? Is the IDEA behind it correct?

I really need to be done at a "global" level without config manual steps on every subscription or putting in some "TenantID" manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've requested a token with scoped for the [Microsoft Graph API](http://graph.microsoft.io) which is why you can use API endpoints surfaced by `https://graph.microsoft.com/`.

The call to `https://management.core.windows.net/subscriptions` is *not* part of Microsoft Graph API so you're token isn't valid for that resource. That call is into the [Service Management REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee460799.aspx). Authenticating for this API is [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx).